# How to add markers dynamically by clicking on the leaflet js map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-leaflet

I want to add markers dynamically by clicking on the map using the react-leaflet.

in this code what changes i should do to add that functionality.

```
       <MapContainer
          center={position}
          zoom={8}
          scrollWheelZoom={true}
          style={{ height: "100vh", width: "100%" }}
        >
          <TileLayer
            attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>       contributors'
        url="https://api.maptiler.com/maps/basic-v2/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?key=INhIiarNdRvjpXL4KRsE"
      />
    </MapContainer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting the onClick can be a bit tricky, my solution is often to just use the `useMapEvents` hook. Since you use react we should attack it as a regular react problem. Use a state to store the markers and then just map over them to render the markers.

Something like this:

```js
interface OnClickProps {
  onClick: (latLng: LatLng) => void;
}
const OnClick: React.FC<OnClickProps> = ({ onClick }) => {
  const map = useMapEvents({
    click(event) {
      onClick(event.latlng);
    },
  });

  return <></>;
};

const position = { lat: 59.9139, lng: 10.7522 };

const LeafletMap: React.FC = () => {
  const [markers, setMarkers] = useState<LatLng[]>([]);
  return (
    <MapContainer
      center={position}
      zoom={8}
      scrollWheelZoom={true}
      style={{ height: "100vh", width: "100%" }}
    >
      <OnClick onClick={(latLng) => setMarkers((curr) => [...curr, latLng])} />
      {markers.map((marker) => (
        <Marker key={`marker-${marker.lat}-${marker.lng}`} position={marker} />
      ))}
    </MapContainer>
  );
};
```